# Mouse accuracy issues in R/place clone

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've been struggling to resolve an accuracy issue in my R/Place clone. Sometimes a pixel is placed dead center of the mouse click, other times its noticeably off.  It's specifically, the getpixelsclicked function that determines where a user has clicked on the canvas is not providing accurate coordinates. This is a significant problem, as I want to enable a cooldown feature to limit the frequency at which pixels can be placed in the future and the clicks need to be 100% accurate.

I've uploaded a much-simplified version here on jsfiddle. My original code uses a grid that's 1500x1000px

https://jsfiddle.net/1m92Ly70/

```
const draw = function ({ x, y, color }) {
  x = Math.round(x / 12) * 12;
  y = Math.round(y / 12) * 12;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 12, 12);
  ctx.fill();
};

const getPixelClicked = function (canvas, event) {
  const x = Math.floor(event.offsetX / 12) * 12;
  const y = Math.floor(event.offsetY / 12) * 12;
  const color = "#000000";
  return { x, y, color };
};
```

To address this issue, I have tried using various methods in the getpixelclicked function, including getboundingrect, event.x and event.y, pageX and pageY, Math.round, and Math.ceil aswell as no rounding at all. All methods seemed to slightly increase the inaccuracy and not improve it. The closest I have come to resolving the issue is by using Math.floor and rounding to the nearest even number. However, this approach is still not precise enough. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried calculating x and y by using the clickEvent's clientX and clientY properties?

You would then need to subtract the boundingrect values (left for x, top for y)

Comment: I forgot to add that to my main post but I have tried that aswell and it seems to be a bit more off than using the current method. Its weird even barebones code with no css im still getting the issue

Comment: There is nothing wrong with mouse events' `offsetX` and `offsetY`. The cursor type `"default"` has a focus point inside its black border pixel/s . As pointed out the cursor type `"default"` is not intended for pixel perfect use. Use the cursor type `"crosshair"` as it is specifically designed to select pixels. It does not change the accuracy of mouse clicks as that is unrelated to cursor type. I does however give you better visual feedback as to where your click will be. Also #888 is the wrong canvas BG color for crosshair.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is mostly correct. A couple of clarifications:
`event.offsetX`/`event.offsetY` are correct to use here, as they give you the coordinates relative to the event target (the canvas).

Using `Math.floor` here is also correct, cause you always want to round down. E.g.: given a click at `(5, 25)`, you want to round this to pixel `(0, 2)`.

You don't need the `Math.round` in the draw function, cause you will always get whole numbers (integers) there anyway. You've already rounded in the `getPixelClicked()` method. However, IF you decide to round there for any reason, you also want to round with `Math.floor`, cause the same logic applies for drawing pixels.

I've tested the fiddle and it feels mostly accurate, except for when drawing on the border of a pixel, where it's not 100% clear where the pixel will be drawn. Maybe changing the cursor type to a crosshair would help there.

I also suggest to highlight the pixel that the user is about to draw on. That will make drawing more predictable.